# confusion between versions of microsoft.sharepoint.dll

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In my SharePoint application I use 3 versions of Microsoft.SharePoint.dll (version 12 for SharePoint2007, version 14 for SharePoint2010, and version 15 for SharePoint2013). The problem is all three of those DLLs have the same namespace. I even changed the assembly name (to add it to the references) but, the namespace is still the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/27/774692.aspx

Short story:

First of all, we must rename the assembly to have the possibility to added it to the project

- "just right click the assembly -> Rename"

Second:

- Go to the properties of the assembly and change the alias to other alias like "SP2010" just at the first line in the class add "extern alias SP2010;"

Third:

- use `SP2010::Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication` instead of `SPWebApplication` etc

Comment: Please add more details to this answer! How was it resolved? If the link breaks, this answer will be of no help to future readers

Comment: First of all, we must rename the assembly to have the posibility to added It to the project "just right click->remane" , second: go to the proprieties of the assemly and change the alias to other alias like "SP2010"and just at the first ligne in the class add "extern alias SP2010;",third : use "SP2010::Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication" instead of "SPWebApplication" and so on , i hope that It help

Answer (score 0):

standard way to solve these issues is to use different build configurations for the project (Debug12, Debug14, Debug15). Each build configuration should have own unique compilation directive (Debug12 -> SP2007, Debug14 -> SP2010, Debug15 -> SP2013). Then use conditional referencing in Visual Studio vsproj file to reference correct version of Microsoft.SharePoint.dll depending on currently used build configuration. The following example is for Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll, but it will be similar for Microsoft.SharePoint.dll as well:

```
  <Choose>
    <When Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'debug' Or '$(Configuration)' == 'release' ">
      <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=16.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
          <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
          <HintPath>..\Assemblies\16.1\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll</HintPath>
          <Private>True</Private>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime, Version=16.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
          <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
          <HintPath>..\Assemblies\16.1\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
          <Private>True</Private>
        </Reference>
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
    <When Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'debug15' Or '$(Configuration)' == 'release15' ">
      <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
          <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
          <HintPath>..\Assemblies\15\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll</HintPath>
          <Private>True</Private>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
          <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
          <HintPath>..\Assemblies\15\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
          <Private>True</Private>
        </Reference>
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
  ...
  </Choose>
```